# Demonstrative adjectives/pronouns

Tags: grammar, demonstratives

In the sentence 'Are those english newspapers?' the word 'those' is a demonstrative adjective or pronoun? 
My english book says that a demonstrative is an adjective if it is followed by a noun (like in 'those newspapers are interesting'), is this true also for questions like that one?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's neither! Here, the demonstrative determinative "those" is the independent form functioning as a 'fused' determiner-head. It's used deictically and understood as "those newspapers".

Answer (score 1):

As your English book says, the difference is whether the demonstrative "is followed by" a noun.

ADJ

Those English newspapers are old. (But these English newspapers are new.)

PRO

Those are English newspapers. (But these newspapers are Spanish.)

To take a simple English sentence using "to be" and turn it into the equivalent question, we have to swap the positions 1 and 2 in the sentence (You are => Are you?)
So looking at the question versions of the examples I wrote:

ADJ

{Those English newspapers} {are} {old}.

Are those English newspapers old?

PRO

{Those} {are} {English newspapers}.

Are those English newspapers?

Comment: Thanks, in your second example 'these' is used as an adjective right?

Comment: I don't know which one you are referring to as 'second'. 
In the examples following ADJ,  "those" is used as an adjective.
In the examples following PRO "those" is used as a pronoun.

Comment: I was referring to 'But these newspapers are Spanish'.